# How to implement animated application states on Windows 10 Taskbar

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-10

---

Whenever you install dependencies to Visual Studio 2019 or specific applications are working in the background on particularly long tasks, they show a visual behavior in the bottom "Task Bar" panel of Windows.

They can either have the [Loading/Working Behavior Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvXfO.png) on their icon or something like an [Alert Behavior Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XP6r.png).

I'd like to learn about this feature, however I've looked thoroughly here and on Google and have not found anything! Anyone got some literature, docs or hints on how to achieve this? I'd like to implement this with a WPF .NET Core C# app. Hope that it supports this behavior.

Thanks in advance for any hints and solutions! :)

Comment: [ITaskbarList3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions#progress-bars) implementation. I believe you can do that in WPF using [TaskbarItemInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo?view=net-5.0) Class.

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks!